# how can i repeat a code that i write in a form key down event each time i press that key

Tags: c#, events, methods, keydown

in c# how can i repeat a code that i write in a form key down event each time i press that key
i mean i want to re run that code each time i press the key
i think this can be so simple for u cause i am beginner
thanks
this code is what i already tried

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)

        {

            textBox1.TabStop = true;
            dataGridView1.Focus();
            label1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();



        }
```

Comment: You'll have to improve on your title making.

Comment: oh it's right with u :D

Comment: As suggested by @SergioTulentsev please improve your title. Also let us know what issues you faced when you tried your code.

Comment: can i edit this question title ? if i can , how?

Answer (score 1):

The `key_down` code should just repeat and loop around every time the assigned key is pressed, as the subroutine is just called over and over again on every key down event.

Comment: But it will not be repeated when i pressed the key

Comment: Yes, it will be executed again, if you press the key again.

Comment: @Aprogrammer as said above, it is executed each time you press the key. Have you tried this? If so, try pressing it again but leave a longer time after pressing it before doing so again. If it still doesn't work then something is wrong.